# Complex analysis problem from Lars Ahlfors' book

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was reading Lars Ahlfors' book on Complex Analysis, 3rd edition and encountered a problem which I could not solve:

> Prove that
> $$\left|\frac{a-b}{1-\bar{a}b}\right|=1$$
> if either $|a|=1$ or $|b|=1$. what exception must be made if $|a|=|b|=1$?

At first, I substituted $|a|=1$, and after that $|b|=1$, and it worked. But I think that the problem is asking me to 'prove' it.
I noticed that
$$\left|\frac{a-b}{1-\bar{a}b}\right|=\frac{|a-b|}{|1-\bar{a}b|}$$
So the equation is
$$\frac{|a-b|}{|1-\bar{a}b|}=1$$
Squaring both sides gives
$$\frac{|a-b|^2}{|1-\bar{a}b|^2}=1$$
Now I used the formula
$$|a-b|^2=|a|^2+|b|^2-2\Re(a\bar{b})$$
which turns the equation to
\begin{align}
|a|^2+|b|^2-2\Re(a\bar{b})&=1+|a\bar{b}|^2+\Re(a\bar{b})\\
|a|^2+|b|^2&=1+|a\bar{b}|^2
\end{align}
What can be done now?
Note: I am not too experienced in mathematics. I am studying it as a hobby, but math is not my field. It may happen that I missed something 'trivial'.

Comment: You were almost there. Just note that $|a\bar{b}|^2 = |a|^2 \cdot |b|^2$, so that your last equation can be written as $(1-|a|^2)(1-|b|^2) = 0$.